# Pandas, how to multiindex an existing DataFrame that's data comes from JSON. How to alter JSON object through pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, indexing, multi-index

I have files containing JSON objects as below:

```
{"v": "1","uuid": "c62f3e001c5a43d7bc663eef7db5372c","source": 3,"uniqueName": "hive","sensorId": 8324,"alarm": false,"date": 1497387606620,"movement": 49280,"rssi": 362,"lux": 16,"magnet": 16,"ageSent": 69206224,"ipAddress": "0.0.0.0","locationSensorId": 0,"locationCounter": 0,"readerId": 67,"geo": {"x": "1","y": "1","z": "1"},"sys": {},"fa": {},"requestOriginTypeId": 2,"failover": {"adv": 1,"oi": 1,"c": 1,"cr": 1},"D": "3","W": 24,"M": 5,"Y": 2017,"user": {"ui": "0","id": "0","cntry": "UK","cty": "NEWBY","gender": 0,"age": 0,"dt": 0,"scr": 0},"resp": {"rid": 67,"adv": 10000001,"oi": 1,"c": 1,"cr": 1,"p": 1.0,"b": 1.0,"curr": "£","rb": 1}}
```

I have a problem were I need to access the value "adv": 100000001 here:

```
"resp": {"rid": 67,"adv": 10000001,"oi": 1,"c": 1,"cr": 1,"p": 1.0,"b": 1.0,"curr": "£","rb": 1}
```

Because of the format, my dataFrame contains a column "resp" with values:

```
{"rid": 67,"adv": 10000001,"oi": 1,"c": 1,"cr": 1,"p": 1.0,"b": 1.0,"curr": "£","rb": 1}
```

What's the best way to access that value? I'm thinking around creating a series from {u'adv': 1, u'cr': 1, u'c': 1, u'oi': 1} (the value(s) under "resp")

I have another problem this being my main problem. I have a large df created from the json above that will eventually only contain the columns

```
df_json = df_json[['day_time','sensor_id','customer_id','rssi','date','time']]
```

Previous to this some columns were renamed, which is why you may not see a correlation in the json.

currently the data looks like below (day_time = date only [see first row]/ it was date, but date will be near the end of df):

```
                   day_time  sensor_id  customer_id  rssi  advertiser_id  \
0   2017-03-17                 4000068           76   352        1000001
0   2017-03-17 09:20:17.708    4000068           56   374        1000001
1   2017-03-17 09:20:42.561    4000068           60   392        1000001
0   2017-03-17 09:44:21.728    4000514           76   352        1000001
0   2017-03-17 10:32:45.227    4000461           76   332        1000001
0   2017-03-17 12:47:06.639    4000046           43   364        1000001
0   2017-03-17 12:49:34.438    4000046           62   423        1000001
0   2017-03-17 12:52:28.430    4000072           62   430        1000001
1   2017-03-17 12:52:32.593    4000072           62   394        1000001
0   2017-03-17 12:53:17.708    4000917           76   335        1000001
```

I need this df to be multiindexed by day_stamp and sensor_id so that the data (please correct me if I am wrong!) will appear as:

```
          date  sensor_id  customer_id  rssi  advertiser_id  \
0   2017-03-17     4000068           76   352        1000001
0                                    56   374        1000001
1                                    60   392        1000001
0   2017-03-17     4000514           76   352        1000001
0   2017-03-17     4000461           76   332        1000001
```

The reason I want the data in this format is so that I can apply the .diff() function to the time, and work out the difference in time between each record for each sensor_id.

I believe there is a problem with this as well. As the time.diff() will end up finding the difference in time between one ID and another. Is there anyway to contain the diff() method to find the time difference between records with the same sensor_id?

I want to stress again that my main problem is multiIndexing the existing df (feel like there is 5 questions here). How would I output day_time and sensor_id as valid arrays that could be used in the multiIndex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
print (df)
                  day_time  sensor_id  customer_id  rssi  advertiser_id
0               2017-03-17    4000068           76   352        1000001
0  2017-03-17 09:20:17.708    4000068           56   374        1000001
1  2017-03-17 09:20:42.561    4000068           60   392        1000001
0  2017-03-17 09:44:21.728    4000514           76   352        1000001
0  2017-03-17 10:32:45.227    4000461           76   332        1000001
0  2017-03-17 12:47:06.639    4000046           43   364        1000001
0  2017-03-17 12:49:34.438    4000046           62   423        1000001
0  2017-03-17 12:52:28.430    4000072           62   430        1000001
1  2017-03-17 12:52:32.593    4000072           62   394        1000001
0  2017-03-17 12:53:17.708    4000917           76   335        1000001
```

---

```
df['day_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day_time']).dt.date
df = df.set_index(['day_time','sensor_id']).sort_index()
print (df)
                      customer_id  rssi  advertiser_id
day_time   sensor_id                                  
2017-03-17 4000046             43   364        1000001
           4000046             62   423        1000001
           4000068             76   352        1000001
           4000068             56   374        1000001
           4000068             60   392        1000001
           4000072             62   430        1000001
           4000072             62   394        1000001
           4000461             76   332        1000001
           4000514             76   352        1000001
           4000917             76   335        1000001
```

Comment: That creates an index by day_time, but still has sensor_ids as a mix e.g sensor_id still looks as it does in my sample data.

Comment: Maybe help [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html)

Comment: I find some pandas docs hard to understand, would I do sort_index(axis=index, level= not too sure)

Comment: Yes, but I think it is not necessary, because axis=0, level=0 are default values, so can be omited.

Comment: Perfecto! Thank you! I was sure it needed a multi-index, one thing I am sure of is I need to some pandas course :D

Comment: Do you have any recommendations or things to look at to fix the json object as value problem under a column resp? Would creating a series from the object be best?

Comment: It depends what you need, but if need 2d data `DataFrame` is best.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the differences, you can use transform. something like

```
df['time_diff'] = df.groupby(('date', 'sensor_id')).transform('diff')['day_time']
```

should work

Comment: That is actually the old way I did it, but I'm interested in the transform('diff').

Also there is another reason why the groupby wasn't useful I just can't remember at this point :(

Comment: I found this [blog post](http://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html) very enlightening about `transform`

Comment: As soon as I seen the picture of how it works I was so happy! Am I correct in saying this is exactly what I need? Indexes df correctly and transform allows the diff method to be applied to groups of same sensor_ids and wont find the difference in time between two different ids?

Comment: @DanielCull What do you mean with `difference in time between two different ids` Have you tried it on your larger dataset? Transform gets passed a chunk of the DataFrame (the data of 1 `(date, sensor_id)`- combination, and applies the function `diff` on that chunck. Then you assign a new column `time_diff` in the original DataFrame to this diff of column `day_time`

Comment: Yep I realised that, I was laughing at myself that I asked the question will this work the way I think it works, when the blog you posted really does spell it out.

Also I remebered my original problem with my groupby and it didn't have to be a problem! I grouped by too many columns, thinking I needed to to have all the columns, and forgetting I could merge your ['time_diff'] with the df after

Comment: @MaartenFabré - do you test solution? It return `keyerror`

Comment: you have to add the column `date` indeed, but from what I read in the OP, that column was somewhere further down the DataFrame

Comment: with:

          df_json['time_diff'] = df_json.groupby(by=['day_time', 'sensor_id']).transform('diff')['date']

I get:

TypeError: diff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

How do I make things look like code in comments :(

Comment: @daniel-cull why would you group by `day_time` and then take the diff of the `date` instead of the other sway around? all `day_time`s seem to be unique to me, so not much grouping

Comment: My sample data was slightly incorrect. 'day_time' contains dates only and no time, to group df by days. 'date' includes the date and time and what I would apply the diff to. With the way you have done it, I also get a keyError: 'day_time'

Comment: that's confusing. I have no idea where the `TypeError` comes from. It works here

Comment: @Maarten Fabré  The only reason I got a keyError was because I had included jezrael's sorting when I ran the script, removed it, and your version works! Except obviously 'day_time' only contains dates so 'time_diff' only conatins NaN's

Why did the axis error appear?

Comment: Something VERY confusing happened. I had df_json['time'] = df_json.date.dt.time (this was never used however, so I changed it to df_json.date (time = date) and applied the diff method on time, which works! But because they are identical that made me go wtf why does this work, so I tried the diff() on date and it now works...? I just put df_json.date.dt.time back and now it does not work (axis error), whats the correlation here?

Comment: Transform is applying the diff function very strangely, not as it normally would have. Sections that should not have NaT have it, anywhere that is a time is repeated across all instances of the sensor_id in question

Comment: Thiese loose comments are confusing me. If your sample data was wrong, please repair that in the original question, and add the details of these extra questions there or open a new question. Showing the data you want is very hard in comments

Comment: Above was fixed using  lambda x: x.diff()